# Understanding the serialization and the deployment of a custom untyped plutus core implementation

Tags: plutus, plu-ts

I have found [this](https://github.com/HarmonicPool/plu-ts) open source project that aims to create a typescript library to write smart contracts.

I had a look at the code but was not able to understand a couple of main pieces useful to understand the whole picture.

Of course the author is following the [Plutus Core Specificiation](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus/blob/master/plutus-core-spec/draft-new-specification/plutus-core-specification.pdf) in order to create the library, but to me is not clear where the actual serialization happen.

Also, when the serialization is done, how will be possible to push it to the computational layer of the blockchain? Should we crate a particular transaction containing the obtained binary code?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Searching in the existing folders I ended up finding the [`UPLCEncoder`](https://github.com/HarmonicPool/plu-ts/blob/main/src/onchain/UPLC/UPLCEncoder/index.ts) implementation.

in particular, the class exposes a [`compile method`](https://github.com/HarmonicPool/plu-ts/blob/f9b0b81056b98b7a0bd95daec5d0bcddbe32ce2f/src/onchain/UPLC/UPLCEncoder/index.ts#L283) that has the following signature:

```
compile( program: UPLCProgram ): BitStream
```

so it is something that given a `UPLCProgram` instance returns a `BitStream`; the implementation of the [`BitStream` class](https://github.com/HarmonicPool/plu-ts/blob/main/src/types/bits/BitStream/index.ts) suggest it is a wrapper ona `bigint` js primitive value used to store the compiled program.

back to the `compile` method; the library already supports [hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting); so the first part of the method is about inlining hoisted terms;

the actual compilation is forwarded to the `encodeTerm` method as we can see from

```typescript
result.append(
    this.encodeTerm(
        progrTerm
    )
);
```

the [implementation of `encodeTerm`](https://github.com/HarmonicPool/plu-ts/blob/f9b0b81056b98b7a0bd95daec5d0bcddbe32ce2f/src/onchain/UPLC/UPLCEncoder/index.ts#L324) is just an intermediate step to choose the encoding to use based on the actual `UPLCTerm` instance passed.

once `encodeTerm` understands the type of the terms calls the specific encoding function that translates 1:1 the `UPLCTerm` to binary (using `BitStream`) and calls again `encodeTerm` (mutually recursive) when necessary as in the case of `Application` encoding

```typescript
const result = Application.UPLCTag;
this._ctx.incrementLengthBy( result.length );

result.append(
    this.encodeTerm( app.funcTerm ) 
);

result.append(
    this.encodeTerm( app.argTerm )
);
```

once `compile` returns the `BitStream` currently the solution is to use the `toBuffer` method to get a `Buffer` from it and convert it to the serialized hexadecimal string that can be submitted in a transaction, just like any other smart contract.

it has to be said that the project is quite new so I'm sure there will be a more direct way to obtain the hexadecimal string.